# Can't get HTTPS working with Azure Front Door, AKS and Traefik

Tags: azure, azure-aks, traefik, traefik-ingress, azure-front-door

I'm trying to setup Azure Front Door Premium in front of an AKS cluster with Traefik 2.5.3 as an ingress controller.

This is the relevant configuration in AFD:
[image]

I've got the following `IngressRoute`s and `Certificate` setup in AKS:

```
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: IngressRoute
metadata:
  name: my-domain-web
spec:
  entryPoints:
    - web
  routes:
    - match: Host(`my-domain.com`)
      kind: Rule
      services:
        - name: whoami
          port: 80
---
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: IngressRoute
metadata:
  name: my-domain
spec:
  entryPoints:
    - websecure
  routes:
    - match: Host(`my-domain.com`)
      kind: Rule
      services:
        - name: whoami
          port: 80
  tls:
    secretName: my-domain-com-cert
---
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: Certificate
metadata:
  name: my-domain-com-cert
spec:
  commonName: my-domain.com
  secretName: my-domain-com-cert
  dnsNames:
    - my-domain.com
  issuerRef:
    name: letsencrypt
    kind: ClusterIssuer
```

Requesting over HTTP works:

```
> curl http://my-domain.com
Hostname: whoami-84d974bbd6-ff77m
IP: 127.0.0.1
IP: ::1
IP: 10.9.0.56
IP: fe80::4467:5bff:fee0:731b
RemoteAddr: 10.9.1.106:58076
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: my-domain.com
User-Agent: curl/7.68.0
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Via: 1.1 Azure
X-Azure-Clientip: <redacted>
X-Azure-Fdid: <redacted>
X-Azure-Ref: <redacted>
X-Azure-Requestchain: hops=1
X-Azure-Socketip: <redacted>
X-Forwarded-For: 10.9.0.4
X-Forwarded-Host: my-domain.com
X-Forwarded-Port: 80
X-Forwarded-Proto: http
X-Forwarded-Server: traefik-6f49dccb4b-kv5c7
X-Real-Ip: 10.9.0.4
```

But requesting over HTTPS doesn't work:

```
> curl https://my-domain.com
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN' 'http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd'><html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'><head><meta content='text/html; charset=utf-8' http-equiv='content-type'/><style type='text/css'>body {font-family:Arial; margin-left:40px; }img  { border:0 none; }#content { margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto }#message h2 { font-size: 20px; font-weight: normal; color: #000000; margin: 34px 0px 0px 0px }#message p  { font-size: 13px; color: #000000; margin: 7px 0px 0px0px}#errorref { font-size: 11px; color: #737373; margin-top: 41px }</style><title>Service unavailable</title></head><body><div id='content'><div id='message'><h2>Our services aren't available right now</h2><p>We're working to restore all services as soon as possible. Please check back soon.</p></div><div id='errorref'><span>0ksK6YgAAAADgd38yzqpIQasLDS0yNDFmYTUxODMyMjk=</span></div></div></body></html>%
```

In the Traefik logs I can see the following:

```
time="2022-06-28T09:05:22Z" level=debug msg="Serving default certificate for request: \"\""
time="2022-06-28T09:05:22Z" level=debug msg="http: TLS handshake error from 10.9.0.4:20734: EOF"
```

Here are the diagnostic logs from Azure Front Door:
[image]

I can't really figure out what the issue is... Could it be that the host header isn't propagated correctly so that Traefik doesn't know how to route it? I have enabled access logs in Traefik, but they don't log anything (I guess the request never reaches that far).

**EDIT:**
Turns out it's related to Traefik serving the request using the default self signed (invalid) Traefik cert.

I can get around this by setting a valid default cert in Traefik (using a `TLSStore` CRD), and disabling "Certificate subject name validation". I'm not sure what subject name is expected, but it isn't `my-domain.com` since that's what the cert contains.

Comment: I think I've figured out that this is related to SNI (since this is related to HTTPS). 

The TLS handshake happens before the server can read the HTTP headers (the Host header containing my-domain.com).

So it will depend on what SNI the Azure Front Door is sending, and that seems to be empty since I'm setting an IP as Host name in the AFD configuration.

Not really sure what the best option is here though, but at least I think I understand the issue.

Comment: have you figured out how to make Azure Front Door to send a proper SNI?

Comment: @AntonMatsiuk In my case the origin configured in AFD is the DNS name of the load balancer in front of AKS, something like mycluster.cloudapp.azure.com (can’t remember it exactly). Which will be used for SNI. If I create a CNAME like mycluster.mydomain.com (pointing to mycluster.cloudapp.azure.com) and use that as origin in AFD, that will be used for SNI. And since it’s a domain I control, I can generate a certain for it. Then Traefik will serve that cert (for all routes) but route based on the correct Host header.

Comment: thanks for the hint! I'm trying to reproduce a very similar setup on AWS with EKS and ELB pointing to Traefik and adding a CNAME for `mycluster.mydomain.com ` pointing to DNS name of ELB worked, Traefik fetches a proper certifcate in this case as Azure sends a proper SNI in this case. Unfortunately, this setup is very poorly documented on Azure side.